# C# Vector<double>.CopyTo barely faster than non-SIMD version?

Tags: c#, html, vector, simd

*UPDATE: The span issues that were mentioned previously were fixed in the .net core 2.1 release (which is currently in preview.) These actually made the Span Vector *faster* than the array Vector...*

NB: Testing this on a "Intel Xeon E5-1660 v4" which CPU-Z tells me has Instructions for "MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, EM64T, VT-x, AES, AVX, AVX2, FMA3, RSX" so it should be OK...

Off the back of answering a [Vector based question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49164908/136675), I thought I would try to implement some BLAS functions. I found that ones that were reading/summing such as dot product were pretty good, but were I was writing back to an array were bad - better than non-SIMD, but barely.

So am I doing something wrong, or is there more work in the JIT required?

The example (assuming x.Length = y.Length, not null etc. blah, blah):

```
public static void daxpy(double alpha, double[] x, double[] y)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
        y[i] = y[i] + x[i] * alpha;
}
```

In Vector form becomes:

```
public static void daxpy(double alpha, double[] x, double[] y)
{
    var i = 0;
    if (Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated)
    {
        var length = x.Length + 1 - Vector<double>.Count;
        for (; i < length; i += Vector<double>.Count)
        {
            var valpha = new Vector<double>(alpha);
            var vx = new Vector<double>(x, i);
            var vy = new Vector<double>(y, i);
            (vy + vx * valpha).CopyTo(y, i);
        }
    }
    for (; i < x.Length; ++i)
        y[i] = y[i] + x[i] * alpha;
}
```

And, playing around in .NET Core 2.0, I though I would try Span, both naive and Vector form:

```
public static void daxpy(double alpha, Span<double> x, Span<double> y)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
        y[i] += x[i] * alpha;
}
```

And Vector

```
public static void daxpy(double alpha, Span<double> x, Span<double> y)
{
    if (Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated)
    {
        var vx = x.NonPortableCast<double, Vector<double>>();
        var vy = y.NonPortableCast<double, Vector<double>>();

        var valpha = new Vector<double>(alpha);
        for (var i = 0; i < vx.Length; ++i)
            vy[i] += vx[i] * valpha;

        x = x.Slice(Vector<double>.Count * vx.Length);
        y = y.Slice(Vector<double>.Count * vy.Length);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
        y[i] += x[i] * alpha;
}
```

So the relative timings on all these are:

```
Naive       1.0
Vector      0.8
Span Naive  2.5 ==> Update: Span Naive  1.1
Span Vector 0.9 ==> Update: Span Vector 0.6
```

So am I doing something wrong? I could hardly think of a simpler example, so I don't think so?

Comment: did you look into `IL` generated by vectorized version ?

Comment: @Tigran, nothing looks strange in the IL, and I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with assembly to decypher what should or should not be there...

Comment: @Dai this is c#, not c++...

Comment: In .NET, you may actually get faster performance with a two-pass operation using `System.Buffer.BlockCopy` and then the `* alpha` step.

Comment: Disclaimer, I've never used `Span` before, but reading documentation, I noticed it's a *value type*, In your case, you pass it *by-value* into the function, which invokes a copy on `Span<T>` type.

Comment: @PaulWestcott Ah. My mistake. Your question title says `Vector<double>` - which is an STL type, not .NET.

Comment: @Tigran, please don't guess. Span is a new type that is a wrapper around contiguous chunks of memory, and that is how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: @Tigran IL is almost irrelevant here; the JIT does all the magic

Comment: @Dai `Vector<T>` is .NET's representation of SIMD-enabled vectors, from System.Numerics

Comment: @PaulWestcott do you have a complete example including the initial vector setups? I'm trying to run local, etc

Comment: @MarcGravell: you're right, my bad. I was thinking about jitter, but wrote IL

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to test with 2.1 more than 2.0; 
on my laptop (which has poor SIMD compared to my desktop), I get:

```
daxpy_naive x10000: 144ms
daxpy_arr_vector x10000: 77ms
daxpy_span x10000: 173ms
daxpy_vector x10000: 67ms
daxpy_vector_no_slice x10000: 67ms
```

using code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Numerics;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double alpha = 0.5;
        double[] x = new double[16 * 1024], y = new double[x.Length];
        var rand = new Random(12345);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            x[i] = rand.NextDouble();

        RunAll(alpha, x, y, 1, false);
        RunAll(alpha, x, y, 10000, true);
    }

    private static void RunAll(double alpha, double[] x, double[] y, int loop, bool log)
    {
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for(int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
        {
            daxpy_naive(alpha, x, y);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        if (log) Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(daxpy_naive)} x{loop}: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
        {
            daxpy_arr_vector(alpha, x, y);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        if (log) Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(daxpy_arr_vector)} x{loop}: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");


        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
        {
            daxpy_span(alpha, x, y);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        if (log) Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(daxpy_span)} x{loop}: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
        {
            daxpy_vector(alpha, x, y);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        if (log) Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(daxpy_vector)} x{loop}: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
        {
            daxpy_vector_no_slice(alpha, x, y);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        if (log) Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(daxpy_vector_no_slice)} x{loop}: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }

    public static void daxpy_naive(double alpha, double[] x, double[] y)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
            y[i] = y[i] + x[i] * alpha;
    }

    public static void daxpy_arr_vector(double alpha, double[] x, double[] y)
    {
        var i = 0;
        if (Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated)
        {
            var length = x.Length + 1 - Vector<double>.Count;
            for (; i < length; i += Vector<double>.Count)
            {
                var valpha = new Vector<double>(alpha);
                var vx = new Vector<double>(x, i);
                var vy = new Vector<double>(y, i);
                (vy + vx * valpha).CopyTo(y, i);
            }
        }
        for (; i < x.Length; ++i)
            y[i] = y[i] + x[i] * alpha;
    }
    public static void daxpy_span(double alpha, Span<double> x, Span<double> y)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
            y[i] += x[i] * alpha;
    }

    public static void daxpy_vector(double alpha, Span<double> x, Span<double> y)
    {
        if (Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated)
        {
            var vx = x.NonPortableCast<double, Vector<double>>();
            var vy = y.NonPortableCast<double, Vector<double>>();

            var valpha = new Vector<double>(alpha);
            for (var i = 0; i < vx.Length; ++i)
                vy[i] += vx[i] * valpha;

            x = x.Slice(Vector<double>.Count * vx.Length);
            y = y.Slice(Vector<double>.Count * vy.Length);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
            y[i] += x[i] * alpha;
    }

    public static void daxpy_vector_no_slice(double alpha, Span<double> x, Span<double> y)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated)
        {
            var vx = x.NonPortableCast<double, Vector<double>>();
            var vy = y.NonPortableCast<double, Vector<double>>();

            var valpha = new Vector<double>(alpha);
            for (i = 0; i < vx.Length; ++i)
                vy[i] += vx[i] * valpha;

            i = Vector<double>.Count * vx.Length;
        }

        for (; i < x.Length; ++i)
            y[i] += x[i] * alpha;
    }
}
```

which is using `dotnet build -c Release` and `dotnet run -c Release`, with `dotnet --version` reporting "2.2.0-preview1-008000" (a "daily" from a little while ago).

On my desktop, I would expect the difference to be even better.

Comment: How would you explain that `Span` version is slower somewhat than naive one ? May it because of in `Span` case there is in place accumulation to element, and jitter might optimize that differently ? I just don't see, from the code provided, any other glaring difference other than that. That what puzzled me more than "non sufficient speedup".

Comment: OK, running on ".NET Core 2.1.101" (on the Xeon as from my original positing) I get: [122ms, 83ms, 244ms, 91ms] which is not too dissimilar to my original results. I'll try on some other machines... Maybe the 2.2 release improves things a little... But did think these were supposed to be 4-doubles wide, so even with your better relative results they are still quite bad (as a reference I was comparing against an OpenBLAS implementation - which I wasn't going to get anywhere near, but it ran about 1/5 the time of the Naive version, so I was hoping for 1/3 to 1/4...)

Comment: Oh, and I noticed a little inconsistency in my code, which was that I had "y[i] = y[i] +" in some places and "y[i] +=" in other places. If I swap for the former in naive Span it doubles the time (so now taking 4 times longer than the the naive), but if I swap the latter for the former in the non-Span naive it increases the time by 10-20% (but maybe that's just luck?). Vector Span remains the same(ish).

Comment: Actually the previous comment about the Non-Span naive and the changing of += was only applicable in the 32-bit build (I had just been playing around there...). no difference was noticed in 64-bit. The difference with the Span version remained though.

Comment: On my desktop (which is quite old, but has CPU with SIMD support) I can reproduce OP results. Naive is the fastest, vector is a bit slower, span version is slowest of them all (2x slower than naive and vector). That's on .net 2.1.2

Comment: @PaulWestcott  I would add all that information at the bottom of your question.